# Custom react hook is not fetching values

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I have a custom react hook written that is supposed to fetch a list of categories from a firebase firestore. I then map over this return array to display a list of the categories to the user.

However when I call the custom hook it is not creating the list on the front-end. When I console.log the array it first logs null **then** logs the correct list. I have a feeling that the react component that display the list is trying to display the first value that gets returned which is null.

Below is my custom hook and the component that returns to list:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from '../firebase/firebase';

function useCategories() {

  const [categories, setCategories] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('categories')
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            const fetchedCategories = snapshot.docs.map((document) => (
                document.data().name
            ))
            setCategories(fetchedCategories)
        })

    return () => unsubscribe() // drop subscription to firestore once components unmounts
  }, []);

  return categories
}

export default useCategories;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import useCategories from '../helpers/useCategories';

const CategoriesList = () => {

    const categories = useCategories();

    return (
        <ul>
            {categories && categories.map(category => (
                <li key={category.name}>
                    {category.name}
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
}

export default CategoriesList;
```

I feel like this is probably an easy fix but I have brain mush

Cheers

Comment: What's in `fetchedCategories`? Looks like there are already just names, and then you try to access `.name` on a name?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I'm an idiot you're 100 percent right, category was already just the name I didn't need to access .name, thanks you legend

Comment: You're welcome! (I always knew I'd turn out to be a legend one day!)